# Node has gone away in WWW::Mechanize::Chrome

Tags: linux, perl, google-chrome, mechanize, google-chrome-headless

WWW::Mechanize::Chrome loses somehow the node, when calling a different method like `->find_all_links()`

```
No node with given id found

-32000 at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Chrome/DevToolsProtocol/Target.pm line 490
Node 447 has gone away in the meantime, could not resolve at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/WWW/Mechanize/Chrome/Node.pm line 206.
No node with given id found
```

When I do `$mech->get($url)` again before fetching all links, it's working, but I don't want to re-get URLs every time when we call a method and we need to submit forms later on anyway.

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Chrome->new(
        headless => 1,      
        launch_exe => '/usr/bin/google-chrome',             
        launch_arg => ["--headless" , "--no-sandbox"],
        separate_session => 1,                      
);

&parse_content;
sub parse_content  {  
    $mech->get($url);
    my $content = $browser->content;    
    # parse some content
}
  
# $mech->get($url); 
# fetching the links would work when getting the URL again 
# but this is not the way it should work

my @links = $mech->find_all_links();
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: You are using a global variable to access the object `$mech` inside the subroutine. Pass the object to the subroutine with a variable instead: `parse_content($mech, $url)`.

Comment: Also why are you using that subroutine? It doesn't do anything.

Comment: It does not make a difference (global vs. parsing in func); of course, there is code in the sub not unnecessary for the questions here. Using ->links() only, it worked though. Looks like, WWW::Mechanize::Chrome is accessing this method as a parent method of WWW::Mechanize

Comment: Hello, this seems to be a bug where objects are lost between calls https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=122881 , They said there was a commit already to fix nodes being forgotten between calls, Are you using latest modules. Cause it seems this issue was found in 2017 and perl 5.20 is much older than that

Comment: On that test server, I am using Perl 5.20.2, module have been installed via "cpan -i" command. There fixed it? It still occurs :(